How to calculate the generalized Puiseux series of ${\csc(x)}^{\tan(x)}$ at $x=0$?
First consider this problem: find the limit of ${\csc(x)}^{\tan(x)}$ as $x\rightarrow0$, which is easy:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to0}{\csc(x)}^{\tan(x)}&=\lim_{x\to0}\exp(\tan(x)\ln(\csc(x)))\\
&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to0}-\frac{\sin(x)\ln(\sin(x))}{\cos(x)}\right)\\
&=\exp\left(-\lim_{u\to0}u\ln(u)\right)\qquad(u=\sin(x))\\
&=\exp(-0)\\
&=1
\end{aligned}
$$
Then I use WolframAlpha to check if my answer is correct. WA does give the same answer, but besides the answer, it also gives a weired series expansion called generalzied Puisex series, which is a power series containing fractional exponents and logarithms.
$$
1+x\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\log^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{6}x^{3}\left(\log^3\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+2\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+1\right)+\frac{1}{24}x^{4}\left(\log^4\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+8\log^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+4\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{360}x^{5}\left(3\log^5\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+60\log^3\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+30\log^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+48\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+22\right)+\operatorname{\mathcal{O}}\left(x^{6}\right)
$$
My question is: how to calculate the generalized Puiseux series of ${\csc(x)}^{\tan(x)}$ at $x=0$ ?

$$\csc(x)^ {\tan (x)}=e^{\tan (x) \log (\csc (x))}$$
$$\log (\csc (x))=\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac 16\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\, x^{2n}$$ the first coefficients
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{30},\frac{2}{945},\frac{1}{6300},\frac{2}{155925},\frac{691}{638
   512875},\frac{4}{42567525},\frac{3617}{434188755000},\cdots\right\}$$ do not sem to appear in $OEIS$.
If they did, use the Cauchy product and re-exponentiate.
